# read_table error while reading .idx file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read an .idx file that is about 1.89Gb in size. If I write:

> indexfile=pd.read_table("C:\Edgar Zip files\2001\company.idx")

I get the output as:

- Company Name Form Type CIK Date Filed File Name
- 0 033 ASSET MANAGEMENT LLC / ...
- 1 033 ASSET MANAGEMENT LLC / ...
- 2 1 800 CONTACTS INC ...
- 3 1 800 CONTACTS INC ...
- 4 1 800 FLOWERS COM INC ...

Where all the columns are merged together in a single column

---

If I do:

> indexfile=pd.read_table("C:\Edgar Zip files\2001\company.idx",sep=" ")

I get the error:

> CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 69 fields in line 4, saw 72

---

I can use:

> indexfile=pd.read_table("C:\Edgar Zip files\2001\company.idx",error_bad_lines=False)

But that will just remove most of my data.

Is there any workaround?

PS: Link to a sample .idf file [SEC EDGAR](ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/full-index/). Download the company.idx file.

Answer (score 0):

Your column entries also have spaces in them. So use 2 spaces as separator.

```
indexfile=pd.read_table("C:\Edgar Zip files\2001\company.idx",sep="  ")
```

Comment: Still get the error: >Expected 32 fields in line 2, saw 38

Comment: The --------------------- in line 2 could be causing the problem. Try adding error_bad_lines=False or remove the 2nd line from company.idx and try.

Comment: I've actually removed the 2nd line, but I'm still getting the error. Also with error_bad_lines=False it's skipping most of the entries in the table

Comment: Can you paste the error here after removing the 2nd line?

Comment: 'ValueError: Expected 32 fields in line 2, saw 38'